# What does \luaescapestring do for us?

Tags: luatex

It seems that all TeX command are expanded into unexpandable tokens (say, TOKENS1) and these token are converted into some other tokens (say, TOKENS2). For example

```
\directlua{
  local var = [[\luaescapestring{\TeX}]]
  print("*****" .. var .. "*****")}
\bye
```

when finishing excuting `\luaescapestring{\TeX}`, what we get is this

```
  T\\kern -.1667em\\lower .5ex\\hbox {E}\\kern -.125emX
```

---

Why does `\luaescapestring` do this work and why we need this command in LuaTeX?

---

Comment: According to the LuaTeX reference, "this primitive converts a TeX token sequence so that it can be safely used as the contents of a Lua string: embedded backslashes, double and single quotes, and newlines and carriage returns are escaped. This is done by prepending an extra token consisting of a backslash with category code 12, and for the line
endings, converting them to n and r respectively. The token sequence is fully expanded."

Comment: @Paulo Cereda I read the manual, but don't know how to apply this and don't know why we need this.

Comment: Please, don't get me wrong on my quotation from the manual. `:)` I was just pointing at the description. Patrick's answer is very detailed and it will surely help us all. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda oh, I don't mean that. After reading the manual, I said to myself: I can't understand that, so I have to come here and ask this question `:-)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer the second question (first question later):

> Why we need this command in LuaTeX?

Imagine the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \directlua{tex.sprint("#1") }}
\begin{document}
\foo{bar}
\end{document}
```

`\foo{bar}` is expanded to `\directlua{tex.sprint("bar")}` which outputs `bar`.

Now let's change the macro call:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \directlua{tex.sprint("#1") }}
\begin{document}
\foo{"baz"}
\end{document}
```

Now `\foo{"baz"}` gets expanded to `\directlua{tex.sprint(""baz"") }` which is not valid Lua syntax. To protect us from users who want to print quotation marks `"`, one can either check the argument manually (which tends to be very very difficult) or you can rely on the magic of `\luaescapestring{...}` - in LaTeX it's prefixed with `luatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \directlua{tex.sprint("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}") }}
\begin{document}
\foo{"baz"}
\end{document}
```

now it expands to something like this:  `\directlua{tex.sprint("\"baz\"")}`.

To answer the first question:

> Why does \luaescapestring do this work?

`\TeX` is defined in plain TeX:

```
\def\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}
```

so the expansion of TeX is `T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX` which contains `\k`, `\l`, `\h`, which are control codes in Lua's strings (or could be). Therefore `\luaescapestring` adds a backslash to have `\\k`, `\\l` and `\\h` as the string source. Now you have tricked the system by using `[[...]]` to define the string, and in this double bracket string the backslashes don't do any harm. So in your case you didn't have to use `\luaescapestring`.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful explaination. Since I read your code last time, I am curious about the `\luaescapestring` and don't know why we need its help. Now, I understand that :-)